# How to save df.to_csv to a preferred location rather than desktop?

Tags: python, pandas, export-to-csv

i am trying to save df.to_csv file to a preferred location but getting the following error 'the system cannot find the path specified". however when i try to save it on desktop, it works. can anyone pls suggest what am i doing wrong here.

```
import csv
import pandas as pd
import requests
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
import os
London = timezone('Europe/London')
LA_time = datetime.now(London).strftime('%Y_%m_%d_%H')
latest_url = requests.get('https://dsv-ops-toolkit.ihsmvals.com/ftp?config=tradition&lastModified=-1hour&filter=Tradition_Basis_RFR').json()[0]['url']
CSV_URL = 'https://dsv-ops-toolkit.ihsmvals.com/' + latest_url


with requests.Session() as s:
    download = s.get(CSV_URL)
    decoded_content = download.content.decode('utf-8')
    cr = csv.reader(decoded_content.splitlines(), delimiter=',')
    my_list = list(cr)

    df = pd.DataFrame(my_list)
    output_file = 'Tradition_Basis_RFR_' + LA_time + '_00_00.csv'
    output_dir = 'S:\\Valuations\\Market Data\\Tools\\Data\\Tradition\\'

    fullname = os.path.join(output_dir, output_file)
    if not os.path.exists(output_dir):
        os.mkdir(output_dir)
    df.to_csv(fullname, index=False, header=0)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One thing you need to be careful is the use of

```
if not os.path.exists("/test/dir/subdir"):
    os.mkdir("/test/dir/subdir")
```

This snippet only works if `/test/dir/` exist; otherwise it will throw an error.

Comment: ok so now i am getting permission error, like permission denied error

Comment: Can you paste the exact error message? It is hard to say what causes the permission issue.

Comment: uploaded a snap